# Make array unique in multidimensional array php codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, codeigniter, multidimensional-array

I have this array

> Array (
>
> ```
> [0] => Array
>     (
>         [0] => stdClass Object
>             (
>                 [id] => 226
>                 [user_id] => 1
>                 [name] => Eden Corner Tub by Glass - $2099
>
>             )
>
>         [1] => stdClass Object
>             (
>                 [id] => 225
>                 [user_id] => 1
>                 [name] => Blue Quilted Leather Jacket by Minusey - $499
>
>             )
>
>         [2] => stdClass Object
>             (
>                 [id] => 222
>                 [user_id] => 1
>                 [name] => Darling New Bathtub by Duravit - $6300
>
>             )
>
>
>
>     )
>
> [1] => Array
>     (
>         [0] => stdClass Object
>             (
>                 [id] => 226
>                 [user_id] => 1
>                 [name] => Eden Corner Tub by Glass - $2099
>             )
>
>         [1] => stdClass Object
>             (
>                 [id] => 229
>                 [user_id] => 1
>                 [name] => Batman Tumbler Golf Cart - $50000
>
>             )
>
>         [2] => stdClass Object
>             (
>                 [id] => 228
>                 [user_id] => 1
>                 [name] => Swirlio Frozen Fruit Dessert Maker - $60
>
>             )
>
>     )    )
> ```

I have an array of products that I need to make sure are unique.
Need to make this array unique by id. These array are generated by pushing value.

I'm trying to solve this for more than a week now, but I dont get it to work. I know it should be easy...but anyway - I don't get it :D

Comment: What do you mean by unique? Unique by id? And where that array come from? From db?

Comment: Wouldn't `array_unique` work for you?  http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php

Comment: @RonniEgeriis no, it won't, because elements are considered unique by their `string` representation, thus array of arrays won't be uqinue'd correctly. (string) array() is Array + notice.

Comment: Sorry guys, actually i already posted wrong array. this is the correct array to be make unique

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$array = array(

    0 =>  array(  
        "name"   => "test",  
        "id"    =>  4  
    ),  
    1   =>  array(  
        "name" =>  "test2",  
        "id" => 152  
    ), 
    2   =>  array(  
        "name" =>  "test2",  
        "id" => 152  
    )
 );

$newArray = array();
foreach($array as $value) {
    $newArray[$value['id']]['name'] = $value['name'];
    $newArray[$value['id']]['id'] = $value['id']; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($array as $key=>$inner_array)
{
    foreach($array as $key_again=>$array_again)
    {
        if($key != $key_again)
        {
            if($inner_array['name'] != $array_again['name'] AND $inner_array['id'] != $array_again['id'])
            {
                //its okay
            }
            else
            {
                unset($array[$key]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how the arrays are generated, but, if you can change that, you could set the array keys to the IDs directly and check if the id is already set.

Otherwise, you can do the following:

```
$unique = array();

foreach( $array as $values ) {
    if( ! isset( $unique[$values['id']] ) ) {
        $unique[$values['id']] = $values;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will make your array unique:

```
$array = array(
  0 =>  array(  
    "name"   => "test",  
    "id"    =>  4  
  ),  
  1   =>  array(  
    "name" =>  "test2",  
    "id" => 152  
  ), 
  2   =>  array(  
    "name" =>  "test2",  
    "id" => 152  
  ) );

$result = array();

$index = array();

foreach($array as $i => $elem) {
  if(!isset($index[$elem['id']])) {
    $result[$i] = $elem;

    $index[$elem['id']] = 1;
  }
}

echo var_export($result);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'name' => 'test',
    'id' => 4,
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'name' => 'test2',
    'id' => 152,
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work. It could be considered more clean than a `for` loop, but I'm not sure about performance.

```
$array = [
    [ "name" => "test", "id" => 4 ],
    [ "name" => "test2", "id" => 152 ], 
    [ "name" => "test2", "id" => 152 ]
];

array_walk($array, function(&$item, $idx) use($array){
    $matches = array_slice(array_keys($array, $item), 1);
    if (in_array($idx, $matches)) {
        $item = false;
    }
});
$array = array_filter($array);
```

**Edit** Since you updated the data set to work with, you would need to flatten it 1 level:

```
$array = call_user_func_array('array_merge', $array);
```

Comment: Actually i already posted wrong array. this is the correct array to be make unique

Comment: i have tried to flatten it to 1 level, like you told using call_user_func_array function but nothing happened

Comment: Could you provide a JSON dump? It's hard to work a var_dump output

Comment: I somehow flatten the array like this: